# "Unsupported Encryption Type" in S3 Batch Operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm setting up batch operations on my bucket and running into an issue (permissions-based, I believe) when the operation tries to access an encrypted manifest file.

I've set up a `manifest.csv` file that accurately lists the files to operate on. I'm trying to invoke a lambda function upon those files. However, every time the operation runs, it returns:

> "Unsupported encryption type used: SSE_KMS"

I believe it is some sort of access that needs to be defined so I tried loosening the restrictions on my IAM policies and role to see if it would help and it didn't. I tried looking for documentation on KMS keys with batch operations but found none.

Role I'm using is S3-Related Policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Role Trust Relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "batchoperations.s3.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

KMS Key Access Policy:

```
{
            "Sid": "Allow use of the key.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account #>:role/<Role Name>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

I feel like I'm just missing something. Can anybody catch anything I missed?
The batch operations should be able to access an encrypted `manifest.csv` file.

---

Addition:

[Choosing Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbSFN.png)

[Choosing Lambda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynvaD.png)

[Choosing Role mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pegx.png)

[It fails before I can even run it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJs13.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a policy issue, but actually just an issue with the value you're sending as `SSE_KMS` is invalid. [As mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html):

> x-amz-server-side​-encryption 
>   Specifies the server-side encryption algorithm to use when Amazon S3 creates an object.
>
> Type: String
>
> Valid Value: aws:kms, AES256

**For KMS encrytpion, you should be using `aws:kms` as the value you send through** (send it as a string). I don't know what language your Lambda is in, but you can take a look at the appropriate SDK for it ([here's the one for node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property), you can see under putObject properties `ServerSideEncryption: AES256 | aws:kms`)

Comment: I'm not trying to PUT anything to a bucket right now. The problem I have is with batch operations not having access to my KMS key. It needs decrypt access so it can access the manifest file stored within an encrypted S3 bucket. I don't see anywhere within the batch operations page that you can add an encryption configuration. The process works end to end perfectly in a non-encrypted bucket.

Comment: Hmm I see...can you share the batch job details? If it was a policy issue you would have an error such as `access denied on kms key`, this is definitely a configuration issue

Comment: Thanks, I meant the actual job details though if you can, like the configurations for the job operation (you can add it to the question by edited it so that it can format well)

Comment: I will do that instead as the first one turned out horrible haha. One minute.

Comment: I see the images attached, so where do you specify the encryption? Is this set only on the bucket itself, so that the whole bucket is encrypted?

Comment: Correct. All items stored within the bucket are encrypted and that Role mentioned above has encrypt/decrypt access. There's no place to specify encryption within batch operation setup.

Comment: This is interesting, I'm guessing they don't even support it yet, which can be expected from AWS...I can only suggest you try using encryption with AWS S3 managed keys, instead of KMS (if that fits your use case). It might be configured to work with SSE-S3 and not SSE-KMS

Comment: But either way, I recommend you submit an email to AWS support if possible, highlighting this issue

Comment: This was my second suspicion.... thank you. I'll try out the S3 key and if that doesn't work, I'll get in contact with somebody from AWS.

Answer (score 5):

SSE_KMS is currently (as of 26/05/2021) not supported on the manifest:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-create-job.html#specify-batchjob-manifest

Comment: That's right, as the docs says: "S3 Batch Operations does not support CSV manifest files that are AWS KMS-encrypted."

Answer (score 0):

Custom KMS encrypted CSV file in S3 Batch Operations is not accepted in S3 Batch Operations.

But S3 Inventory Report's KMS encrypted manifest.json is accepted in S3 Batch Operations.

I tried to place **custom KMS Encrypted CSV File in the format of S3 Inventory Report** and tried if it actually works or not. I found out it works actually.

I have documented the same in [Workaround for S3 Batch Ops CSV Manifest File KMS Restriction](https://medium.com/@agrawalsam1997/workaround-for-s3-batch-ops-csv-manifest-file-kms-restriction-bedd85c18a7a).